# nvim-dap debugging with Ipython instead of the default REPL

Tags: neovim, python, debugging

I wanted to ask if it is possible to combine nvim-dap with ipython for debugging purposes in a reasonable way.

Now I am using the repl that is being opened by nvim-dap-ui. But it is not the most convenient interactive python session. Compared to ipython, it doesn't accept multi-line inputs, doesn't handle plotting with matplotlib, has very verbose and bloated output and is just more cumbersome to work with (cmp-dap was a nice improvement providing completion suggestions).

Alternatively I sometimes use `from ipython import embed; embed()` which allows me to start an ipython session loading the stack at the location in the code where this line was inserted. Then I have nvim in one tmux pane, ipython in another and using vim-slime I can easily execute code in ipython without leaving the nvim pane or use ipython to investigate, plot etc. But I'm missing out on the nvim-dap functionality like step into, set breakpoint, go to cursor and many others which make the debugging experience similar to that of an IDE.

I suppose that it might not be possible to simply replace the default repl with ipython but could there be alternative solutions like making the two operate at the same time? Could ipython connect to the stack of my debugged script without terminating the debugging? Or would it be possible to do it the other way i.e. start ipython in a particular code location with `from ipython import embed; embed()` and then connect to the stack via the nvim-dap 'attach remote' option in the starting selection menu?

I have to say that my knowledge of how the relevant components (nvim-dap, debugpy, ipython, python processes) interact is very limited so I see how what I want could be impossible or not easily achievable. But knowing that this won't work would also be great!

Lastly, maybe someone knows how to limit the verbosity of the nvim-dap repl to not display all the fields of an object? This would be a minor consolidation prize.